# SMTP and POP3 server difference

Tags: java

I have safe mail host ,receiver email id and sender email id.
I am able to send a mail . But If i want to retrieve mail coming to sender email id.Can I use the same mail host ?
or will i need to have another pop3 server in order to fetch the email?

Answer (score 1):

SMTP is used to send email and POP3 is used to receive/download emails. So to retrieve/download emails you need to use POP3 host. You need to see POP3 host detail in your capanel.

it looks like :
SMTP Host Example: smtp.gmail.com
POP3 Host: pop.gmail.com

Comment: thanks for the response . so same mail host can not be used to send or receive the mail.

Answer (score 1):

SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protofol) is used by client software to send emails. IMAP or POP3 are used to receive emails.

So, if you send using SMTP server, you will have to use POP3/IMAP server for receiving.

Comment: thanks for the response . It means our emails resides on POP3 and IMAP server. So depending on the protocol . we need to choose appropriate server like pop3 server for pop3 protocol etc .

Comment: For example, Dovecot supports both POP3 and IMAP interfaces to receive email from it: http://cnedelcu.blogspot.ru/2014/01/how-to-set-up-simple-mail-server-debian-linux.html It stores only one mailbox copy.